# Creating a vec of struct using a loop

Tags: rust

error: "temporary value dropped while borrowed consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value"

```
main () {
        let mut valid_transactions = Vec::new();
        let mut transaction_pool = TransactionPool::new();
        // Create new transactions
        // Invlaidate some push them to the transaction pool
        // Push the valid ones into valid_transactions
        for i in 0..10 {
            let mut transaction = Transaction::new(&state, &recipient, amount);
            if 1 % 3 == 0 {
                // Invalidate transaction by changing the input amount
                transaction.input.amount = 999999.9;
            } else if 1 % 3 == 1 {
                // Invalidate transaction by changing the signature
                transaction.input.signature =
                    Wallet::new(&state.secp).sign(&state, &mut vec!["wrong data".to_string()]);
            } else {
                valid_transactions.push(&transaction.clone());
            }
            transaction_pool.set_transaction(&transaction.clone());
        }
        assert_eq!(
            valid_transactions,
            transaction_pool.valid_transactions(&state)
        );
 }
```

Tried declairing a variable inside the loop and set it equal to foo.clone() as I thought it was a problem with foo being mutable, but it didn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: I believe your problem is the use of `&` and `clone` when adding a transaction to the `valid_transactions` vector. The `clone` function will return a copy the the `transaction` object, then because `&` has a lower precedence, you're trying to take the address of that copy. And since you're not binding that copy to anything, Rust is not liking it.

Comment: Please provide the full error message and a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare your variable `transaction` in the loop, that variable only lives in that iteration of the loop. This means that that at the end of the iteration of the loop, the `transaction` value is freed. This will result in having data that will point to freed memory after the end of the loop. Rust is trying to prevent you from doing this with this error.

You have to move the value of transaction into the vector. You should do something like this:

```rust
      for i in 0..10 {
            let mut transaction = Transaction::new(&state, &recipient, amount);
            if 1 % 3 == 0 {
                // Invalidate transaction by changing the input amount
                transaction.input.amount = 999999.9;
            } else if 1 % 3 == 1 {
                // Invalidate transaction by changing the signature
                transaction.input.signature =
                    Wallet::new(&state.secp).sign(&state, &mut vec!["wrong data".to_string()]);
            } else {
                let transaction_clone = transaction.clone();
                valid_transactions.push(transaction_clone);
            }
            transaction_pool.set_transaction(transaction);
        }
```